# Assign DataGridView.SelectedRows to List

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I accomplish assigning `SelectedRows` from a `DataGridView` to multiple lists?

I've been trying to do this with `foreach` and `for` loop statements, but it is not producing the expected results. It only displays the first row regardless of which row is selected.

How can I make the `for` loop statement search only for selected rows? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
List<string> dTitle = new List<string>();
List<string> dSku = new List<string>();
List<string> dPrice = new List<string>();
List<string> dDesc = new List<string>();
List<string> dImage = new List<string>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvProducts.SelectedRows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgvProducts.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        dSku.Add(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        dTitle.Add(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        dPrice.Add(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        dDesc.Add(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
        dImage.Add(dgvProducts.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

[image: dgvProduct - the DataGridView]

Comment: No error, but not producing the expected results. It only displays the first row regardless of which row is selected. How can I make the for loop statement search only for rows selected? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to use the nested loop to do this.

```
List<string> dTitle = new List<string>();
List<string> dSku = new List<string>();
List<string> dPrice = new List<string>();
List<string> dDesc = new List<string>();
List<string> dImage = new List<string>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvProducts.SelectedRows)
{
    dSku.Add(r.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    dTitle.Add(r.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
    dPrice.Add(r.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    dDesc.Add(r.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
    dImage.Add(r.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
}
```